# importing a dict vs parsing a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an application saving data on the disk in a key-value format. The file can get rather large. I want my python script to read in this data, and I am wondering - if I format this data as a valid python dict `{key1:value1,key2:value2...}` and then import the file to use it, would this present any significant performance improvement compared to reading in a text file, splitting it to `key:value` pairs and storing it into a dict?

Thanks

Comment: How large is large? For files smaller than a couple megs just reading the file off disk is usually the limiting factor. Is it tabular data (then use HDF5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my samples I will assume, `dct` holds the dictionary we want to load.

## Loading dict from `repr(dct)`

Saving values into file in string created by `repr(dct)` is one option.

This file can be load by:

```
import ast
def fromdct(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

## Loading dict from JSON file

```
import json
def fromjson(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

## Loading data by importing Python module

Assuming **data.py** with following content:

```
data = {"a": 11, "b": 22, ...large dictionary}
```

You can read the data by

```
from data import data
```

## Performance (import from module is fastest)

For testing, I created a dictionary with 1 million of key - value pairs:

```
>>> dct = {"a" + str(i): for i in range(1000000)}
```

serialized (skipped here)

and measured time needed to get the data into a variable:

```
>>> %timeit fromdct("data.dct")
1 loops, best of 3: 5.21 s per loop
>>> %timeit fromjson("data.json")
1 loops, best of 3: 773 ms per loop
>>> %timeit from data import data
1 loops, best of 3: 2.15 µs per loop
```

As we see, loading data from Python module is really fastest

## Possible optimizations

- using simpler `json` library, these can be faster
- saving the file into gzipped file - this might speed up reading from disk (does not apply to importing from Python module)

## Alternative - store data in Redis

You might run into problems, if amount of data in the dictionary gets bigger, it may occupy too much memory. This might become critical, if you have to read the data from multiple instances of your program.

Here, Redis might help. It allows storing key-value pairs, where values are always some binary data. You have to serialize them, typically by pickle or JSON.

The advantages are:

- ability to read values one by one, no need to load into memory all at once
- ability to share the data between multiple instances of program
- possibility to run Redis on another server and communicating over TCP, you use memory of another computer
- Redis persist the data to disk
- ability to change data key by key

Disadvantages:

- Redis has to be installed
- All data are in memory (can be resolved by partitioning to multiple instances)
- In some scenarios (abruptly killed server) you may loose latest changes in the configuration

## Conclusions

- Loading from Python module is the fastest method
- Loading from JSON works pretty well
- Loading by `ats.literal_eval` is very slow
- Using Redis might be solution, if amount of data is bigger and the data are needed in multiple programs at once.

Answer (score 4):

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a standard way to store dict-like data, and there exist very fast implementations to read/write JSON data, e.g. the one in python's [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html). Try:

```
import json
with open(f) as F:
    data = json.load(F)
```

If you can compromise file-format human-readability, you can also try using [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) (a binary JSON encoding).